# How to remove a user from a MySQL Database once they have verified themselfs with there email

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with a MySQL Database. I need to have a feature where a user can remove themselves from a database by entering there email address, then it will ask them if they are 100% sure they want to remove themselves and then it will remove them from the database. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the page which displays the current users on the database - http://www.ironicwhiplash.com/join/members.php

*EDIT* I didn't mean I wanted someone to write the code for me! Sorry if it came across that way as it is early in the morning and I am trying to get this done fro tomorrow because I said it would be done! Thank you Joao for the very helpful answer!

*EDIT 2* I have made the code by using the code by the aforementioned post by Joao. Below is the final code that it used :) Hope it can help someone.

I used one page where the user put in there email address:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Leave</title>
</head>


<body>
<form action="remove.php" method="post">
<label style="color:#000">Email:</label><br/>
<input name="email" type="email" required="required" style="color:#000">   <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Leave" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I had another file called 'remove.php':

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="username"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="database name"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="tablename"; // Table name 

// Connect to server.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$email=$_POST['email']; //Fetch the email address from the last page and set it     as a variable called '$ email'

$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name
WHERE email='$email'"; //Delete the user where the email address is the same     as the one which they put in the last form
$result=mysql_query($sql); //Find the result of the executed code

if($result){
echo "Successfully Removed"; //Tell the user if it was removed successfully
}
else {
echo "ERROR"; //Tell you if there is a error.
}
mysql_close(); //Close your SQL connection

?>
```

Charlie :)

Comment: Welcome. But unfortunately SO **is not a free coding site** If you have a go at it and still have problems we are more than willing to help. However we **dont do it all for you**

Comment: Are you asking for the sql js php? Regardless,  this question needs to show work on your end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. I think you just want to do a `delete from` MySQL command.

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp) for more information.

Comment: No I think he wants someone to write the whole script for him!

Comment: No I just need some lines of code RiggsFolly! I'm not the best at PHP and SQL. Thank you for that that's exactly what I needed Joao!